# java How to get the list from a string by the specified symbol?

Tags: java, string, substring

example I have a string

> `"123<a>3213<b>3434343<c>,example <d><1><2><3>"`

I want to get the inner text by the symbol `"<>"`

how can I get the list  **[a,b,c,d,1,2,3]**???

Comment: What is special about the characters you are trying to get?

Comment: You could use some sort of special stack implementation. Similar to if you were trying to validate opening closing `{}`s or `()`s like a compiler.

Comment: Have you tried any regular expressions and/or pattern matching?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes I think  regular expressions can do that, but it is hard for me to write  regular expressions...so..

Comment: So you could practice with them so they aren't so hard. As a programmer they are really useful and you should become familiar with them anyway.

Comment: Don't give up. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) is the tutorial on regexes in Java. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is the javadoc of `Pattern`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [StringUtils.substringsBetween(String str,
                         String open,
                         String close)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringsBetween%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
String[] parts = StringUtils.substringsBetween("123<a>3213<b>3434343<c>,example <d><1><2><3>", "<", ">");
```

Answer (score 5):

You want the text between `<..>`. Use a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) over the given `String` while grouping the text between `<..>`

```
String text = "123<a>3213<b>3434343<c>,example <d><1><2><3>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<(.*?)>"); // reluctant quantifier
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
List<String> entries = new LinkedList<>();
while (matcher.find()) 
    entries.add(matcher.group(1)); // group 0 is the whole match, we only want what's between <>
System.out.println(entries);
```

This prints

```
[a, b, c, d, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Untested, hardly bullet proof, little error checking, but it should work. Of course things could be better, this is just from memory.

```
public List<String> getThings(String source) {
    char[] chars = source.toCharArray();
    boolean capturing = false;
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    String token = "";

    for(char c : chars) {
        if (!capturing) {
            if (c == '<') { // found open delimiter, start capture.
                capturing = true;
                continue;
            }
        } else {
            if (c == '>') { // Found closing delimiter, stop capture.
                results.add(token);
                token = "";
                capturing = false;
                continue;
            }
            token = token + c;
        }
    }
    if (!scanning) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Source string ended with missing closing '>'");
    }
    return results;
}
```